# The existence of a closeness matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> A matrix $U$ is a *closeness matrix* to $A$ if for every $\epsilon\ne0$, $A+\epsilon U$ is invertible.

For example, for $0$, $I$ is a closeness matrix as $\epsilon I$ is invertible, and for $I$ a matrix with a single non-diagnal 1 is  a closeness matrix.
The general question is

> does a closeness matrix alway exist?

If $A$ is diagnalizable, $A=SDS^{-1}$ and $P$ is a matrix with a single non-diagonal 1, then $SPS^{-1}$ is a closeness matrix.
A specific example I've not managed to show has a closeness matrix is $$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: For your example take $U=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Oh, yeah, might that be generalized?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us show that every matrix $A \in \text{M}_n(\Bbb C)$ has a closeness matrix.

- If $A \in \text{GL}_n(\Bbb C)$, we can take $U=0$.
- If $A \not \in \text{GL}_n(\Bbb C)$ write
  $$
  A=P^{-1} T P
  $$
  where $T$ is a triangular matrix such that $T_{1,1},...,T_{l,l}=0$ and $T_{i,i} \neq 0$ for $i > l$. Take $V \in \text{M}_n(\Bbb C)$ such that $V_{1,1},...,V_{l,l}=1$ and $V_{i,j}=0$ for $(i,j)\neq (1,1),...,(l,l)$ and take $U = P^{-1} V P$. We get
  $$
  A + \epsilon U = P^{-1} (T+\epsilon V) P
  $$
  and $\det(A + \epsilon U) = \det(T+\epsilon V) \neq 0$ because we replaced the zero diagonal coefficients of $T$ by $\epsilon \neq 0$.