# existence of an invertible closeness matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> A matrix $U$ is a *closeness matrix* to $A$ if for every $\varepsilon\in\mathbb R,\varepsilon\ne0$, $A+\varepsilon U$ is invertible.

For example, for $0$, $I$ is a closeness matrix as $\varepsilon I$ is invertible, and for $2\times2$ identity matrix $I$ is $\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}.$
The general question is

> does a real invertible closeness matrix always exist?

A specific example I've not managed to show has an invertible closeness matrix is $$\begin{pmatrix}1&5\\0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$
A close companion of [The existence of a closeness matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4196035).
This post was motivated by noting that most of the found closeness matrices are singular.

Comment: Yes, the general existence of the matrix is in the referenced question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be a real $n\times n$ matrix. Then $A$ has a real invertible closeness matrix $U$ over $\mathbb R$ if and only if $n$ is even or $A$ is singular.

By using elementary row and column transformations (or by rank factorisation), we can write $A=PDQ$ where $P,Q$ are inveritible and $D=I_r\oplus0$ for some $r$ (it's actually the rank of $A$, but that is unimportant here).

When $n$ is even, let $R=\pmatrix{0&-1\\ 1&0}$ and we can set $U=P(R\oplus\cdots\oplus R)Q$. If your example where $A=\pmatrix{1&5\\ 0&1}$, you may take $P=A,D=Q=I$ and $U=AR=\pmatrix{5&-1\\ 1&0}$.

When $A$ is singular, we can set $U=PCQ$, where $C$ is the circulant permutation matrix
$$
\pmatrix{0&1\\ &\ddots&\ddots\\ &&\ddots&1\\ 1&&&0}.
$$

When $n$ is odd and $A$ is invertible, if $U$ is any invertible matrix, then $AU^{-1}$ has a real eigenvalue $\lambda$ (because $n$ is odd) which is nonzero (because $AU^{-1}$ is invertible). Therefore $\det(A-\lambda U)=0$.